# Difference between glOrthof and glViewPort

Tags: android, opengl-es, 2d, orthographic

On OpenGL-ES i'm confused on what the difference is between setting

```
glOrthof()  
glViewPort()
GLU.gluOrtho2D()
```

with it's respective parameters. Since I believe it's all setting the part you can see to the specified coordinates (width, height). Which should I use?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The [glViewport](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/glViewport.html) determins the portion of the window to which OpenGL is drawing to.  This may be the entire window, or a subsection (think console game's "split screen" mode- a different viewport for every player).

[glOrthof](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glOrtho.xml) applies an [orthographic projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection) to the current matrix, which is usually set to the projection matrix before this call.  The projection matrix is combined with the modelview to produce a matrix that translates your OpenGL coordinates to screen coordinates.

[gluOrtho2D](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluOrtho2D.xml),

> This is equivalent to calling glOrtho with near = -1 and far = 1.

I'd recommend [this page](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html) for more details on how viewing and transformation works in OpenGL.

Which should you use?  Viewports and orthographic projections are different concerns, so you'll need a call for each.  glOrthof and gluOrtho2D are roughly equivalent; know the difference and use one or the other.

Comment: about the split screen mode, does this mean glViewport is like pointing to a location in the 3d world? btw i'l study the link when I can find some time ;) thanks!

Comment: And if I for example would do something like scrolling through the world/map, translate ALL of the objects or change the glViewport or the glOrtho projection? (sorry couldn't edit anymore)

Comment: The viewport has nothing to do with the 3D world.  It has to do with the final screen coordinates.  To move things around in 3D space you want to glRotate/glTranslate when the modelview matrix is active.  Definitely check out that link.